# Find area of cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ that satisfies $0 \le z \le y$

Tags: calculus, area

I think I can imagine the shape of surface area. This is what I did:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\text{Surface area} & = & \int_{0}^{\pi} r y \sqrt {2} \, d\theta \\
 & = & \int_{0}^{\pi} r\cdot  r \sin \theta \sqrt {2}\, d\theta
\end{eqnarray*}$$

But my answer is not correct.  Where is my mistake?  Thank you

Comment: Where did the $\sqrt 2$ come from?

Comment: My idea was finding d(arc) and multiply by slant height to find element of surface area.  The slant height is line z = y so I thought the length will be Hypothenuse of triangle with base y and height z and since z = y,  the Hypothenuse will be $y \sqrt {2}$

Comment: But you don't care about the hypotenuse. You're doing area of the surface of the cylinder!

Comment: Now I realize I imagined it wrongly.  Thank you Ted.  @alexander Gruber sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 1):

The height of the surface is $r\cdot sin\phi$.

C is the half-circle $C_x(\phi) = rcos\phi$ $C_y(\phi) = rsin\phi$
$$S=\int_{C}z ds = \int_{0}^{\pi}r\cdot sin\phi\sqrt{\bigl(\frac{dC_x}{d\phi}\bigr)^2 + \bigl(\frac{dC_y}{d\phi}\bigr)^2}d\phi =$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\pi}r\cdot sin\phi\sqrt{r^2sin^2\phi + r^2cos^2\phi}d\phi= r^2\int_{0}^{\pi} sin\phi d\phi = r^2\bigl[-cos\phi\bigr]_{0}^{\pi} = 2r^2$$

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand your working. I think ds is element along the arc of the semicircle. How can ds change into those derivatives?
Btw, there is typo: phi square should be cos square

Comment: I corrected the typo, thanks. The big square root is the speed by which the parametrisation passes the arc. Note that there can be more parametrisations of the same curve but each one can pass it by different speed. So this square root compensates this effect. It is a basic formula in curve integrals.

Comment: I have learnt that.  Thank you for helping